# php $var store Mathematical expression

Tags: php

```
$VAR= 5;
$VAR1=30;
```

> Mathematical expression :- 5 * 60 * 60 + 30 * 60

i.e. 5 and 30 are $VAR and $VAR1 respectively.
how to use this manually in php code and store result in `$RESULT`.

Comment: Do you mean $result = $var*60*60+$var1*60?

Comment: Yes exactely, It will work?

Comment: $result = $VAR * 60 *60 +$VAR1 *60;

Comment: Read it wrong with the :- after the word expression. Thought it was a minus sign

Comment: Yup OK. Meance I have use direct this same line and suppose If I use -$VAR * 60 * 60 + $VAR1 * 60 this expression ,It will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$result = $VAR * 60 *60 +$VAR1 *60;
```

The following link will give you an idea of [order of preferance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: If I use -$VAR * 60 * 60 + $VAR1 * 60 this expression ,It will work?

Comment: Yes ofcourse as @AdrianCidAlmaguer specified `$result = -$VAR * 60 * 60 + $VAR1 * 60` will also work since if `$VAR` is 5 so `-$VAR` will be -5 so the final equation will be -5 *60 *60 + 30 *60

Comment: @Pratiksha You are welcome please vote answers which were helpfull to you and mark one of the answers as your accepted answer. Thank you

Comment: @Pratiksha, just don't forget check one answer as correct ;-)

Comment: Ya sure! It yours only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your expression

```
  <?php

    $VAR = 5;
    $VAR1 = 30;

    $calc = - $VAR * 60 * 60 + $VAR1 * 60;
    echo $calc;
    ?>
```